# Network check in repository test class issue flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

Following TDD architecture, In repository test class, before calling api, checking network connectivity. In test repo, network check is not surpassing and not covering the api call.

This is the repo class

```
class LoginRepositoryImpl extends LoginRepository {
  LoginLocalSrc localSrc;
  late NetworkConnectivity networkConnectivity = NetworkConnectivity.instance;

  LoginRepositoryImpl(this.localSrc);

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, LoginModel?>> loginApiCall(
      String userName, String password, FieldType fieldType) async {
    try {
      var isOnline = await networkConnectivity.checkNetwork();
      if (isOnline) {
        var response = await localSrc.login(userName, password, fieldType);
        return Right(response);
      } else {
        return Left(
            FailureMessage(message: AppStrings.kInternetNotAvailableMsg));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Left(await getError(e));
    }
  }
```

This is repo test class

```
 class TestLoginLocalSrc extends Mock implements LoginLocalSrc {}

class TestNetworkConnectivity extends Mock implements NetworkConnectivity {}

@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<TestLoginLocalSrc>()])
@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<TestNetworkConnectivity>()])
void main() {
  late ModelFinder modelfinder;
  late TestLoginLocalSrc mockLoginLocalSrc;
  late LoginRepositoryImpl loginRepositoryImpl;
  late TestNetworkConnectivity networkConnectivity;

  setUp(() {
    modelfinder = ModelFinder();
    mockLoginLocalSrc = MockTestLoginLocalSrc();
    networkConnectivity = MockTestNetworkConnectivity();
    loginRepositoryImpl = LoginRepositoryImpl(mockLoginLocalSrc);
  });

  void runTestsOnline(Function body) {
    group('device is online', () {
      setUp(() {
        when(networkConnectivity.checkNetwork()).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
      });

      body();
    });
  }



group(' ', () {
    runTestsOnline(() {
      test(
        'should return remote data when the call to remote data source is successful',
        () async {
          // arrange

      when(mockLoginLocalSrc.login("username", "", FieldType.mobile))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => modelfinder.loginModelFun());
      // act
      final Either<Failure, LoginModel?> result = await loginRepositoryImpl
          .loginApiCall("username", "", FieldType.mobile);
      // assert

      expect(result, equals(Left(FailureMessage(message: "error"))));
    },
  );

  test(
    'should return server failure when the call to remote data source is unsuccessful',
    () async {
      // arrange
      when(mockLoginLocalSrc.login("username", "", FieldType.mobile))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => modelfinder.loginModelFun());
      // act
      final Either<Failure, LoginModel?> result = await loginRepositoryImpl
          .loginApiCall("username", "", FieldType.mobile);
      // assert

      verifyZeroInteractions(mockLoginLocalSrc);
      expect(result, equals(Left(FailureMessage(message: "error"))));
    },
  );
});
  });
}
```

This is how it is covering now.

[image]

Comment: Your code neglects to set either `NetworkConnectivity.instance` or the `LoginRepositoryImpl`'s `networkConnectivity` member to the `MockTestNetworkConnectivity` instance, so `LoginRepositoryImpl` continues using the default singleton.

Comment: @jamesdlin what will be the solution

Comment: I told you what your code neglects to do, so just do it; make your test's `setUp` callback either do `NetworkConnectivity.instance = networkConnectivity;` or `loginRepositoryImpl.networkConnectivity = networkConnectivity;`.

Answer (score 1):

> First pass Network instance in repository

```
class LoginRepositoryImpl extends LoginRepository {

  LoginLocalSrc localSrc;
  late NetworkConnectivity networkConnectivity


  LoginRepositoryImpl(this.localSrc, {required 
       this.networkConnectivity});
  
}
```

> Test class

```
// remove this class
class TestNetworkConnectivity extends Mock implements NetworkConnectivity {}


@GenerateMocks([TestNetworkConnectivity])
void main() {
  late TestNetworkConnectivity networkConnectivity;

  setUp(() {
     networkConnectivity = MockTestNetworkConnectivity();
     loginRepositoryImpl = LoginRepositoryImpl(mockLoginLocalSrc, 
      networkConnectivity: networkConnectivity,);
  });

  tearDown(() {
     loginRepositoryImpl.close();
  });
}
```